# How does this look for sanitizing mysqli input?

Tags: php, mysqli

Based on http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php , this looks like a good way for my purposes:

```
$filteredVar = filter_var($myVar, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

The strings I will be inserting to my db will be addresses, dates, prices, and product names, all from db or generated by jquery datepicker or google maps api.

Comment: Epic fail. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  No wonder my patent for the wheel was turned down.

Comment: MySQLi has prepared statements, what is your issue with those?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14303765/1877124 seemed like a well-considered answer.  But maybe PDO is the way to go after all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

CRUD application example for a record creation use-case:

```
$db = new mysqli();

$name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['product_name']);
$desc = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['product_desc']);
$price = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['product_price']);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO products (name, description, price) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?);';
$stmt = $db->prepare();
$stmt->bind_param('ssd', $name, $desc, $price);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Your answer uses a MySQL reserved word `desc` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - this will throw an error.

Comment: The placeholders should have been `?` anyway. I fixed it.

Comment: No, I meant the column name.

Comment: Thanks for your clear, informative answer.  I'm taking your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use prepared Statements. Easier, cleanier and self-maintaining.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("","","","");
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT Cols FROM Table WHERE Col=?");
$mysqli->bind_param(...);
```